# adding events in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger simple alert when particular a tags clicked. This is my html code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/modal-load.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.modal-link').modalLoad();
</script>
</head>
....
<body>
     <div class="hblock-1 text-4 text__uppercase color-7">
           <a class="login btn btn-primary modal-link" href="/login-modal.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal">Log in</a>
           <a href="index.html#" class="register btn btn-primary modal-link">Register</a>
     </div>
</body>
```

And below is my jquery plugin

```
(function($){
     $.fn.modalLoad = function(){
         var $t = $(this);
         $t.on('click',function(){
             alert($(this).attr('href'));
         });
     };
})(jQuery);
```

Nothing error there, but why alert is not triggered? And, is there any more simple jquery plugin structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have you script in the head section, when it is executed the target elements `.modal-link` are not yet present in the dom so the plugin won't be initialized for those elements. So move your script to a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Also need to include jQuery library() - Assuming you already have this as you said there are no errors.

```
<!-- include jQuery library-->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/modal-load.js"></script>
<script>
    //dom ready handler
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.modal-link').modalLoad();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: ok, it works now, i forget to wrap my script into dom ready handler

Answer (score 0):

No plugin needed. Try this:

```
$(function() {

    $('#something').on("click", function() {
    var foo = $(this).attr('href'); 
alert(foo);
})
});
```